# Checkout Infinite loop

Tags: magento2, checkout

My checkout first step have an infinite loop.

Console log give me only a warning

```
jQuery.browser is deprecated
```

Magento log

```
main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Altravista/bookshop/en_US/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css.map'
```

can be this the problem?

No server logs

No networks errors
[image]

How can i debug? I'm going crazy

[image: MAgento 2 chieckout infinite loop]

Comment: check browser network tab if any error.

Comment: no errors in network i update answer whit a stamp

Comment: Have you checked console?

Comment: Any third party extensions?

Comment: no errors in console only jQuery.browser is deprecated just disabled my custon modules and just try with luma theme same error

Comment: disable adblock?

Comment: no ad block but see my magento log upldate please after 30 min it get this  main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Altravista/bookshop/en_US/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css.map'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved changing this

> app/design/frontend/Altravista/bookshop/requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/custom'
    ],
    paths: {
        'popper': 'js/bootstrap/popper.min',
        'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'popper': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
            'exports': 'Popper'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'popper']
        }
    }
};
```

with

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/custom'
    ],
    paths: {
        'popper': 'js/bootstrap/popper.min',
        'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'popper': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'Popper'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'popper']
        }
    }
};
```

remove bootstrap from popper shim

Comment: please add file path for update this changes.